# Way to move a file to another directory without specifying filename in destination directory?

Tags: c++, file-rename

I need a way to move a file to another directory without having to specify the file name in the destination directory.

```
TCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, szFileName, MAX_PATH);

wchar_t* Favfolder = 0;
SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Favorites, 0, NULL, &Favfolder);

wstringstream ss(szFileName);
wstringstream ff(Favfolder);

rename(ss.str(), ff.str()); //Won't work
```

If I use `rename`, `ff.str()`doesn't include the file name, so it won't work.

The proper way to do it would be to write:

`rename(C:\\Users\\blah\\blah\\filename.exe, C:\\Users\\blah\\newdir\\filename.exe);`

What I'm doing is:

`rename(C:\\Users\\blah\\blah\\filename.exe, C:\\Users\\blah\\newdir);`

But I can't figure out a way to include the `filename.exe` in the second example.

Comment: `wstringstream`? Why not `wstring`?

Comment: From what I know (Not 100% positive), if I were to use wstring. It wouldn't give me something like "C:\\...", it would give me some random string of characters.

Comment: Can't you simply copy the filename from your source string onto the end of your target string?

Comment: Wait, nevermind. I just tested wstring.

Comment: I don't know how to do that.

Comment: GetModuleFileName gives me the full directory of the file, not the filename.

Comment: It is operating system specific. You might consider using [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using `wstring`, not a `wstringstream`.

1. Use `find_last_of`([link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/)) to find the position of last `\` in the `ss`.
2. Get the filename by `substr`([link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)).
3. Paste the filename at the end of `ff`.

**EDIT:**
Function which do all the work:

```
int move(const string &oldPath, const string &newDir)
{
    const size_t pos = oldPath.find_last_of('\\');
    const string newPath = newDir + '\\' + (pos == string::npos ? oldPath : oldPath.substr(pos));
    return rename(oldPath.c_str(), newPath.c_str());
}
```

Unfortunately, `rename` doesn't support `wchar_t` so I did have to use a `string`, not a `wstring`